# jquery.proxy in the bootstrap-typeahead.js context

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I was reading the following line of code

```
  items = $.isFunction(this.source) ? this.source(this.query, $.proxy(this.process, this)) : this.source
```

from [bootstrap-typeahead.js v2.1.0](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js).

Can someone explain me
how does `this.source(this.query, $.proxy(this.process, this))` work?

For sure:
1) I suppose `this.source` refers to the function define in (1) and then?

---

(1)

```
    element.typeahead({
        minLength: 3,
        source: function () {
             // some code
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

To brake it down: `items = $.isFunction(this.source) ? this.source(this.query, $.proxy(this.process, this)) : this.source;`

So the Object has a property called source, `this.source` It looks like `this.source` could be an Array or a function. They predicate function `$.isFunction(this.source)` takes an Object and if it is a function, returns true. If it is a function `this.source(this.query, $.proxy(this.process, this))` will get executed.

Now to brake down the `this.source(this.query, $.proxy(this.process, this))` call.

We know from the results of the `$.isFunction(this.source)` call that `this.source` is a Function and it takes 2 arguments. The first, `this.query` I am guessing is a string. The second, `$.proxy(this.process, this))` is the callback Function. The `$.proxy` takes two arguments, a Function and an Object/context and returns a new function. The returned Functions context (`this`) is ensured to be the passed in Object/context.

`$.proxy` looks something like this

```
var proxy = function( func, context ) {
    return ( function() {
        func.apply( context, arguments );
    });
};

//build a new function and set this to window
var newFunction = proxy( someOrtherFunction, window );

//use the new function
newFunction();
```

You can ready more about `$.proxy` here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

The newly created Function generated from the `$.proxy(this.process, this)` is used in the `this.source` Function as a the callback.